# How to disable complete magento site from server?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I have a client who is asking me to Live his site on his server and saying that he will pay me after live completion.

But in future if he refused to pay me then it's a big loss for me.

So, I want to know that is there any extension or feature or script by which I can disable/control my client website in case if he will not pay me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this script in root directory, etc... And you can create new admin and block client admin, but you need understand that is bad idea.
It is look like criminal.

https://gist.github.com/litzinger/48be5876d6bba1509323

Comment: Yes  I know it's a bad idea. But if client changed credentials then how i will execute this script?

Comment: You can run this script from browser www.test.com/create-magento-user.php

Answer (score 1):

You should create empty **maintenance.flag** file and upload it to the root folder. So Magento site will not be loaded.

Comment: But if client changed the credentials then how I will create maintenance.flag.